# How many $n \times n$ integer matrices with bounded entries are diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

I am trying to do some calculations involving the *total number of diagonalizable $n \times n$ integer matrices whose coefficients are within $[-k,k]$*. Denote this number $g_n(k)$. Using Mathematica, I have been able to compute
$$g_2(5)=11690,g_2(6)=23744, g_2(7)=43290, g_2(8)=72864.$$

I computed these by brute force, ie. checking every $2 \times 2$ matrix with integer entries in $[-k,k]$. This is quite inefficient!

> Is there an explicit formula for $g_2(k)$? What about for $g_n(k)$?

I hoped this sequence would be on the OEIS, but it was not.

Comment: Diagonizable over what? The integers, reals, complex, something else?

Comment: @orlp sorry, should have specified that. I meant diagonalizable over the complex numbers. So this question is equivalent to asking how many have no repeated eigenvalues. I will edit the post accordingly tomorrow morning, I am on mobile.

Comment: I just checked $g_2(5)$ but got $14265$. And $g_2(6)=28033$. Here's my code: ```n = 0; Do[mat = {{a,b}, {c, d}}; 
 If[DiagonalizableMatrixQ[mat], n++], {a, -6, 6}, {b, -6, 
  6}, {c, -6, 6}, {d, -6, 6}]; n``` Note that it is *not* equivalent to having no repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: @Chrystomath I thought having repeated eigenvalues and a matrix not being diagonalizable over the complex numbers were equivalent statements. What is the difference?

Comment: @orlp The identity matrix itself has repeated eigenvalues. What is required (for $2\times2$ case) are repeated eigenvalues and either $b\ne0$ or $c\ne0$.

Comment: There's a very brief OEIS table for $g_n(1)$: http://oeis.org/A091470.

Comment: @Chrystomath I rewrote my program and now get those same numbers. Not sure what the error was before. Will correct once I get a few more of them.

Comment: @DescartesBeforetheHorse You should add the sequences $g_n(k)$ to OEIS. They seem worthy of inclusion.

Comment: @Chrystomath will do, and will link once it gets approved.